# How to use AutoMapper to filter Columns before being executed against SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I want to use AutoMapper to map my entities into DTO object. i want to filter my column and then execute them against database, but it will gets all Cols and then does it's mapping :

```
 AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
     cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();
     /* etc */
 });

 ShamsEntities Entities = new ShamsEntities();

 var Res = Entities.Users.AsEnumerable().Select(role => Mapper.Map<User, UserDTO>(role)).ToList();
```

Here is my UserDTO :

```
 class UserDTO
 {
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }

 }
```

And here is my SELECT query :

```
 SELECT [Extent1].[ID] AS[ID],
 [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
 [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
 [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
 [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
 [Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
 [Extent1].[DiskUsed] AS [DiskUsed], 
 [Extent1].[DiskUsage] AS [DiskUsage], 
 [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
 [Extent1].[Telephone] AS [Telephone], 
 [Extent1].[Mobile] AS [Mobile], 
 [Extent1].[Skype] AS [Skype], 
 [Extent1].[IM] AS [IM], 
 [Extent1].[GoogleUserName] AS [GoogleUserName], 
 [Extent1].[CompanyName] AS [CompanyName], 
 [Extent1].[CompanyAddress] AS [CompanyAddress], 
 [Extent1].[CompanyTelephone] AS [CompanyTelephone], 
 [Extent1].[CompanyFax] AS [CompanyFax], 
 [Extent1].[CompanyEmail] AS [CompanyEmail], 
 [Extent1].[Tets] AS [Tets] ...
```

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.EF6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to map (by using AutoMapper) and just retrieve the columns you need from your  database then you should install also [AutoMapper.EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.EF6/)

```
Install-Package AutoMapper.EF6
```

Then instead of:

```
var Res = Entities.Users.AsEnumerable().Select(role => Mapper.Map<User, UserDTO>(role)).ToList();
```

Use the new extension method `ProjectTo` like below:

```
var Res = Entities.Users.ProjectTo<UserDTO>().ToList();
```

Note that you don't need to call `AsEnumerable()` and no need to use `Select()` which is replaced with `ProjectTo()`.

More information about that [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Queryable Externsions" of Automapper.

Instead of calling `Map` you call `ProjectTo`.

```
var Res = Entities.Users.AsQueryable().Select(role => Mapper.ProjectTo<UserDTO>(role)).ToList();
```

See [AutoMapper Docs - Queryable Extensions](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html).